# Morph Between Meshes - I have an errors with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I make the morphing effect based on this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pimbaEE9cjQ

[image]

Because the TRANSFER ATTRIBUTE was removed, I used SAMPLE INDEX instead. But the result has many missing places.

The result without SAMPLE INDEX:
[image]

The result with SAMPLE INDEX:
[image]

What did I do wrong here ??

Comment: You're sampling the points on themselves, I think you should be sampling the base geometry https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4HAt.png

Comment: It's not working, the points disappeared. https://imgur.com/XChG99F

Comment: no, you were on the right track to begin with. you want to sample the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fist off all don't use *sample nearest* node, just use the *index* instead.

I've also seen a similar question before. this might help for future problems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcUSz.jpg

Here are some nodes:
[image]

I have a much more elegant solution, but I'm not ready to share it just yet.
I might update, or link to it when I'm ready (if you want to take a look: https://twitter.com/shmuel_Israel_/status/1651460986379948033).
This should solve your problem in the meantime.

Comment: Can you help me write the Geometry Nodes? I have tried but it not working correctly

Comment: Thanks a  lot, It works :)